# How to check if COPY in SQL is successful

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am copying data from csv file to a table in postgres.
I did it by using statement.execute("COPY ... FROM...") in eclipse.
How do I check or return a value to show if the statement is successful?

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **full** Java code you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String query = "Query";
int result = statement.executeUpdate(query);
System.out.println(result);
```

If result is 0 , no updates, insert, delete was executed (no rows affected) but if you get > 0 then the number returned is the number of row affected

Comment: Hi. I also tried executeUpdate but it does not work for copy statement. It will return a 0 even though the data has already been copied.